# Adding google place API to a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-places-api

I have a form designed with google sheets. Within that form there are fields for country and city. I need these fields to be validated somehow so that when the user types in these cells, autocomplete suggestions appear. This is important for this document as we will be using these fields for data analysis so it is vital that no city is spelt in two different ways (e.g. Paris and PAR)...

Is there any way of linking to google places API to get this working.

If, for example, country is listed in cell A3 and city in B3, ideally the user would enter the country and then the cities suggested in the autocomplete for cell B3 would be filtered to just those within that specified country.

Thanks

Comment: There's no way to make it work as autocomplete suggestions, because while user is editing cell, there's no event that can be catched by Google Apps Script. Just when editing is finished (user pressed enter, or moved to another cell) you can read changed cell value.

Answer (score 1):

Google Forms do not support auto-complete and cannot be made to even with Apps Script.

But you're not without options. Your easiest workaround is to use a **Dropdown** form item and populate it with your list of countries and cities.

Your other option is to use the **Short Answer** form item and couple it with a regex validation keyed only to valid string names for each country or city.